# Ubuntu. Exited with return code 127

Tags: ubuntu

итак,с чего все началось - пробовал пофиксить ошибку `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG` , нашел решение -

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
sudo resolvconf -u`
```

И при вводе последней команды мне выходит эта ошибка -

```
sudo resolvconf -u
/lib/resolvconf/list-records: строка 73: sed: команда не найдена
run-parts: /etc/resolvconf/update.d/libc exited with return code 127
```

Строчки из `list-records`:

```
64 if [ -r /etc/resolvconf/interface-order ] ; then
65 PATTERNS="$(sed -e '
66  s/^[[:space:]]\+//
67  s/[[:space:]].*//
68  s/#.*//
69  /\//d
70  /^~/d
71  /^\./d
72  /^$/d
73  ' /etc/resolvconf/interface-order)"
```

Что с ней делать? Как решить эту проблему?

Файл sources.list

```
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 17.04 _Zesty Zapus_ - Release amd64 (20170412)]/ xenial main restricted

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 17.04 _Zesty Zapus_ - Release amd64 (20170412)]/ zesty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ua.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty main restricted
deb-src http://ua.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ua.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://ua.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ua.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty universe
deb-src http://ua.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty universe
deb http://ua.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates universe
deb-src http://ua.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ua.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty multiverse
deb-src http://ua.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty multiverse
deb http://ua.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://ua.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ua.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ua.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty partner

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security multiverse
deb https://git.gnome.org//browse/glade zesty main
deb-src https://git.gnome.org//browse/glade zesty main
```

Comment: показать нам строку 73 из файла `/lib/resolvconf/list-records`

Comment: Давно не работал с deb-осями, но что-то мне подсказывает, что первую строку в  sources.list надо закоментить.

Comment: Либо вернуть в систему инсталяционный CD (но тогда не комментить первую строку)

Comment: 1 строку в sources.list закоментил, ничего не изменилось

Answer (score 2):

Так написано ж:

> строка 73: sed: команда не найдена

sed в системе есть?
По путям переменной окружения PATH доступен?

ЗЫ а вообще удивительно, что в системе по умолчанию нет sed-a...

Comment: Программа 'sed' на данный момент не установлена. Вы можете установить её, выполнив:
sudo apt install sed . Устанавливаю и пишет - Пакет sed недоступен, но упомянут в списке зависимостей другого пакета.
Это может означать, что пакет отсутствует, устарел, или доступен из источников, не упомянутых в sources.list

E: Для пакета «sed» не найден кандидат на установку

Comment: @The_Tihon Тогда надо разбираться с версией убунты и тем, что прописано в  sources.list, т.к. sed находится в "main" репозитории и проблем с установкой быть не должно.

Comment: @The_Tihon: как установить `sed` на Ubuntu 17.04 лучше как отдельный вопрос спросить (если `sudo apt install sed` не работает для вас). Так как ответ откуда 127 взялось вам уже дали (это означает команда не найдена)